# Elastic Beanstalk Flask application - No module named 'pandas_datareader'

Tags: python

I'm working on a web server application with a Python backend which uses Pandas Datareader

When I run the application locally on an Ubuntu VM it runs fine but when I deploy it to the web server I get the following log which from what I understand doesn't  see pandas data reader.

I tried uninstalling and re installing it both with pip install pandas-datareader and then pip install pandas_datareader.

Please help :)

```
    -------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[Sun Jun 07 12:32:15.387285 2020] [:error] [pid 4207] [remote 172.31.33.209:14780]     from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
[Sun Jun 07 12:32:15.387299 2020] [:error] [pid 4207] [remote 172.31.33.209:14780] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
[Sun Jun 07 12:32:30.805655 2020] [:error] [pid 4207] [remote 172.31.33.209:188] mod_wsgi (pid=4207): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Jun 07 12:32:30.805702 2020] [:error] [pid 4207] [remote 172.31.33.209:188] mod_wsgi (pid=4207): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
[Sun Jun 07 12:32:30.805778 2020] [:error] [pid 4207] [remote 172.31.33.209:188] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jun 07 12:32:30.805801 2020] [:error] [pid 4207] [remote 172.31.33.209:188]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:32:30.805805 2020] [:error] [pid 4207] [remote 172.31.33.209:188]     import robot_developer as rd
[Sun Jun 07 12:32:30.805819 2020] [:error] [pid 4207] [remote 172.31.33.209:188]   File "/opt/python/current/app/robot_developer.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:32:30.805826 2020] [:error] [pid 4207] [remote 172.31.33.209:188]     from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
[Sun Jun 07 12:32:30.805841 2020] [:error] [pid 4207] [remote 172.31.33.209:188] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:27.698446 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4201] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:28.819977 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 4882] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:28.836087 2020] [so:warn] [pid 4882] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:28.838333 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 4882] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:28.838345 2020] [http2:warn] [pid 4882] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:28.838893 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 4882] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:28.838956 2020] [:warn] [pid 4882] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:28.838962 2020] [:warn] [pid 4882] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.10.
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:28.841330 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4882] AH00163: Apache/2.4.43 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:28.841349 2020] [core:notice] [pid 4882] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:31.804618 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:31.804672 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:31.805023 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:31.805057 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:31.805062 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     import robot_developer as rd
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:31.805069 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/current/app/robot_developer.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:31.805073 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:31.805100 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:32.809017 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:208] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:32.810857 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:208] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:32.821304 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:208] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:32.821340 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:208]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:32.821345 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:208]     import robot_developer as rd
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:32.821352 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:208]   File "/opt/python/current/app/robot_developer.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:32.821356 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:208]     from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:32.821372 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:208] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:33.825020 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:33.825068 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:33.825150 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:33.825175 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:33.825180 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212]     import robot_developer as rd
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:33.825187 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212]   File "/opt/python/current/app/robot_developer.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:33.825191 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212]     from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:33.825206 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:34.828842 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:34.828900 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:34.828984 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:34.829009 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:34.829014 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212]     import robot_developer as rd
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:34.829033 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212]   File "/opt/python/current/app/robot_developer.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:34.829037 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212]     from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
[Sun Jun 07 12:40:34.829051 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 127.0.0.1:212] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
[Sun Jun 07 12:41:49.030936 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Jun 07 12:41:49.030989 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
[Sun Jun 07 12:41:49.031076 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jun 07 12:41:49.031103 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:41:49.031108 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]     import robot_developer as rd
[Sun Jun 07 12:41:49.031116 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]   File "/opt/python/current/app/robot_developer.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:41:49.031120 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]     from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
[Sun Jun 07 12:41:49.031135 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:01.104687 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:01.104738 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:01.104822 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:01.104847 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:01.104861 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]     import robot_developer as rd
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:01.104869 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]   File "/opt/python/current/app/robot_developer.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:01.104872 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]     from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:01.104887 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:57.858877 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:57.858926 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:57.859008 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:57.859032 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:57.859037 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]     import robot_developer as rd
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:57.859044 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]   File "/opt/python/current/app/robot_developer.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:57.859048 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]     from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
[Sun Jun 07 12:42:57.859063 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
[Sun Jun 07 12:44:09.425678 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Jun 07 12:44:09.425733 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
[Sun Jun 07 12:44:09.425816 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jun 07 12:44:09.425842 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:44:09.425846 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804]     import robot_developer as rd
[Sun Jun 07 12:44:09.425853 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804]   File "/opt/python/current/app/robot_developer.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:44:09.425857 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804]     from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
[Sun Jun 07 12:44:09.425872 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:18.616377 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:18.616430 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:18.616515 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:18.616539 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:18.616544 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]     import robot_developer as rd
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:18.616551 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]   File "/opt/python/current/app/robot_developer.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:18.616555 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212]     from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:18.616570 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:212] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:58.378808 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:58.378859 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804] mod_wsgi (pid=4887): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py'.
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:58.378943 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:58.378980 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:58.378984 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804]     import robot_developer as rd
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:58.378991 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804]   File "/opt/python/current/app/robot_developer.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:58.378995 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804]     from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
[Sun Jun 07 12:46:58.379009 2020] [:error] [pid 4887] [remote 172.31.33.209:14804] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
```

Comment: Is this module defined as a dependency, e.g. in a `requirements.txt` file or `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`?

Comment: So I just used eb init with a linux VM I haven't made a pip freeze to requirements.txt

Would that be something I should try ?

Comment: Yes. You need to define _all_ of your dependencies so Elastic Beanstalk knows what to install.

Comment: Thanks Chris I forgot to pip freeze. just finished it and now deploying will let you know if it works :)

Comment: 2020-06-07 13:34:08    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2020-06-07 13:34:14    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2020-06-07 13:34:42    ERROR   Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
2020-06-07 13:34:45    ERROR   [Instance: i-0f5547b573d5c4404] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip i

My web appication is using python 3.6.10

Comment: and from webserver logs 

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
      install_dependencies()
    File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
      check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 190, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)

Comment: @Chris  this is my requirements.txt file part 1

appdirs==1.4.3
attrs==19.3.0
awsebcli==3.18.1
bcrypt==3.1.7
blessed==1.17.6
botocore==1.15.49
CacheControl==0.12.6
cached-property==1.5.1
cement==2.8.2
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
colorama==0.4.3
contextlib2==0.6.0
cryptography==2.9.2
cycler==0.10.0
distlib==0.3.0
distro==1.4.0
docker==4.2.1
docker-compose==1.25.5
dockerpty==0.4.1
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.15.2

Comment: part 2 
EB==0.1.5
Flask==1.0.2
future==0.16.0
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.7
importlib-metadata==1.6.0
ipaddr==2.2.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
jmespath==0.10.0
jsonschema==3.2.0
kiwisolver==1.2.0
lockfile==0.12.2
lxml==4.5.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.2.1
msgpack==0.6.2
multitasking==0.0.9
numpy==1.18.5
packaging==20.3
pandas==1.0.4
pandas-datareader==0.8.1
paramiko==2.7.1
pathspec==0.5.9
pep517==0.8.2
pkg-resources==0.0.0

Comment: I'm a noob with this :| 

progress==1.5
pycparser==2.20
PyNaCl==1.4.0
pyparsing==2.4.6
pyrsistent==0.16.0
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytoml==0.1.21
pytz==2020.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.20.1
retrying==1.3.3
semantic-version==2.5.0
six==1.11.0
termcolor==1.1.0
texttable==1.6.2
urllib3==1.24.3
wcwidth==0.1.9
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==0.57.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
yfinance==0.1.54 zipp==3.1.0

Comment: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg-resources==0.0.0

Seems like this was causing the problem currently deploying it without this pcakgage

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me .

pip freeze > requirements.txt

deploy application to AWS

check server logs in EB console to see what is wrong. 
if any package is giving errors like in one of my comments remove it and re-deploy

Thank you !!!!!!